# tastypie filter data in front-end

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

I am using `Tastypie` to filter data in backend

```
class Meta:
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'inventory'
    filtering = {'barcode': ALL}
```

in `api/v1/inventory/?format=json&barcode=1232141542625235624` i got filtered data by `barcode`

How can i use it and filter it in front-end using AngularJS ?

```
app.controller('InventoryListCtrl', function($scope, Inventory, Restangular, inventoryItems) {
$scope.inventories = inventoryItems;
};
```

My State

```
app.config(function config( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('inventory',{
    url:'/inventory',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/main.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Inventory' }
    }
    ).state('inventory.listview',{
    url:'/listview/',
        views: {
            "listview": {
                controller: 'InventoryListCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/inventory.listview.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Listview' },
        resolve: {
            inventoryItems: function(Inventory, $stateParams){
                return new Inventory().query();
            }
        }
    })
```

have my template

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
     <li>{{inventory.manufacturer}} {{inventory.model}}</li></a>
      <li><b>Barcode:</b> {{inventory.barcode}}</li>
      <li><b>Holder:</b> {{inventory.user.first_name}} {{inventory.user.last_name}}</li>
      <li><b>Tags:</b> {{inventory.tags.tags}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the data from the REST interface using an asynchronous call. See e.g. the documentation for [ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).